# I have uninstalled Microsoft/windows store app from my laptop, how do I reinstall it?

Tags: windows-11, reinstall, windows-store-app, windows-store, microsoft

I have uninstalled windows store app from my windows 11 laptop unintentionally and now am finding it very difficult to reinstall it.. could some one recommend the best way to get it right?

Comment: just cant find a store app anywhere on my pc.

Comment: What reinstallation methods have you tried so far? Which instructions did you follow? Did you check if Microsoft has instructions, or something's available with internet search? Please don't answer in a comment, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768124/edit) your question instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.